# Bypass verification of particular commit in Gerrit

Tags: git, teamcity, gerrit

I setup Gerrit + TeamCity for automatic verification of changes. But this verification is relatively long and not always relevant. Is it possible skip verification (but not review) of commits with, say, changes only in *.txt files?

One solution I can imagine - setup dummy, empty task in Teamcity for 'verify' such changes, but seems it is not natural way...

Update:

More details about used approach.

1. I setup Gerrit and made basic setup for demo project.
2. I setup TeamCity VCS trigger for track changes in git repo refs/changes/* and run build on every commit (actually every proposed patch set).
3. I setup TeamCity feature commit-status-publisher (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Commit+Status+Publisher) for this build configuration, so it publish status of every patchset.

Comment: Is this about https://github.com/maxifier/teamcity-gerrit-plugin and https://timothybasanov.com/2011/08/31/teamcity-gerrit.html from 2011?

Comment: Not quiet. I use different (but similar - commit-status-publisher) plugin and slightly different approach (no hooks - use teamcity vcs trigger). Though general idea is the same.

Comment: Sure, but do edit your question with more details and links then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your question: set a Teamcity task to approve "special" changes. Another idea: you could create a Gerrit hook to approve these changes, The [Git::Hooks](https://metacpan.org/release/Git-Hooks) could be used for this.